# Finding additive inverse using OpenSSL BIGNUM

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl, bignum

I need to calculate the additive inverse of a large (BIGNUM) prime in C.  So, basically, i need to multiply by -1.  Is there an easy way to do this that i've missed?  I don't see any functions in the documentation.  All i've come up with is this, which i think is rather ugly:

```
//bigprime = my big prime
inverse = BN_new();
one = BN_new();
negOne = BN_new();
BN_one(one);  // one = 1
BN_zero(negOne); // set negOne to zero
BN_sub(negOne, negOne, one) // subtract one from zero
BN_mul(inverse, bigprime, negOne, ctx); //multiply big prime by -1
```

More so, i'm not familiar enough with the bignum library to know whether "subtracting" one from zero is really going to do what i want it to.  TIA!

Comment: perhaps it would help to share more about the prime-calculating algorithm you are using. I cannot see any fault with what you provided so far...

Comment: Why not simply subtract `0 - bigprime` (`BN_sub(inverse,zero,bigprime)` apparently)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: D'oh, i think you're right Daniel--that should do it.  I knew i was missing something obvious!

Comment: Daniel if you could post it as an answer instead of a comment i'll flag it as an answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler solution is to just subtract the prime from zero.

```
inverse = BN_new();
nil = BN_new();
BN_zero(nil);
BN_sub(inverse,nil,bigprime);
```

should do it.